# Processing list of keys in python efficiently

Tags: python, file, list

I have an input file with a list of keys (A's) like A_1, A_2, A_3,..., A_N.

I have other 4 other files with key-value pairs (and A is always the key in these files). E.g., File 1 has A-B types, File 2 has A-C types, File 3 has A-D types and File 4 has A-E types.

What I want to do is efficiently attach B, C, D, and E from other files to every A in the input file list like A_1-B1,C1,D1,E1;A_2-B2,C2,D2,E2 and my questions is what would be the ideal thing to do in my case - list of json objects? list of objects (creating a class for each A seen?

P.S. I'm not looking for code. Just ideas will help me started. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into `dict`s?

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is to have a dictionary that uses `A_1`, `A_2`, *etc* as keys that point to lists of `B1`, `C1`, *etc*:

```
{ A_1 : [B1, C1, D1, E1],
  A_2 : [B2, C2, D2, E2],
  # ...
}
```